# Set UITableViewCell Background outside of XIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I can't set the background color of my cells when the table view loads, no matter what it stays the same color as declared in the XIB. This table view will still be white like the XIB:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
}

cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:17.0];

cell.textLabel.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];

UIColor *cellBackColor = [UIColor orangeColor];

cell.backgroundColor = cellBackColor;
return cell;
}
```

What can I do to insure the color in my method is what is on the table view.

Note: Obviously if I can just change it in the XIB but eventually I want the colors to alternate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`UITableViewCell` has a content view. You can access it via `contentView` property. That's why you don't see the cell's color changed. The content view covers the whole frame of the cell and it contains all the views you add to the cell. You can change its `backgroundColor` to see the effect.

And as a better solution, you can assign a new view to `backgroundView` property of the cell.

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:cell.frame];
cell.backgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor];
```

You can use `backgroundView` to set the background to a custom image, as well.

Comment: @anupdas I'm not really acquainted with `CGRectZero`. What does it do?

Comment: This only changes the color behind the text, making the text look as if it is highlighted in white, compared to the entire cell changing colors. It looks much different then when I set the cells background color in an IBAction.   Edit: I just changed the background color in the nib to be be transparent, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to put the code for changing the background color in the willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath: delegate method of the table view:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UIColor *cellBackColor = [UIColor orangeColor];
    cell.backgroundColor = cellBackColor;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method use:

cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];